# Возведение числа в степень по модулю

Tags: математика, криптография

Здравствуйте.
Возвожу число в степень по модулю:

```
(x ^ y) mod N = z
```

Мне известно `y`, `N`, `z`. Как найти `x`?

Comment: Это вопрос по теории чисел, а не по программированию. Ну и думаю, что раз в вопросе речь идёт о криптографии, есть шанс, что задача не решается существенно быстрее перебора.

Comment: @pavel: А чем первообразный корень поможет? Тем более, он существует не по любому модулю.

Comment: @VladD да вы правы, я базовую ссылку дал. Не заметил что есть и такая статья http://e-maxx.ru/algo/discrete_root. Ну и криптография обычно работает за логарифм от числа ( число разрядов например) и считает это медленным, это совсем не перебор в лоб.

Comment: @pavel: Ага, в статье написано, чем первообразный корень катит. Но всё равно, это ж только для простого модуля. Для произвольного там ещё надо исследовать решаемость. Боюсь, это хороший кусок теории чисел.

Comment: @VladD не совсем. Всегда можно разбить задачу на серию задач каждая по простому модулю. Потом пересечь решения.

Comment: @pavel: Ага, точно! Но тут скорее не пересечь, а китайская теорема об остатках.

Answer (score 2):

1. Составное N можно факторизовать и свести исходное сравнение к системе сравнений по взаимно простым модулям - степеням простых чисел.
2. Решение каждого из таких сравнений сводится к решению нескольких сравнений по простому основанию.
3. Решение сравнений по простому основанию рассмотрено в статье по ссылке ОП. Понизить степень такого сравнения можно с помощью малой теоремы Ферма.
4. Зная классы искомого числа по взаимно простым модулям, нетрудно восстановить класс этого числа по их произведению, т. е. по основанию N.

Подробности по пп. 1, 2, 4 - в книге [И. М. Виноградова](http://mathscinet.ru/files/VinogradovIM.pdf), гл. IV.